# Input html not displaying the LESS (<) character

Tags: html, input, tags

I have an html form in which i've got this input:

`<input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="${messageDetails.description}" maxlength="500" />`

If i submit the code in this form: `x < y` it will only display `x`, what is after the char `<` is ignored. Can you please help me?

Comment: can you explain better?..i don't understand..wha's the problem?

Comment: The character "<" is breaking my HTML code and what is beyond "<" is not displayed after submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [special characters](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html), not to break your HTML .

In your case `x<y` should be replaced by `x &lt; y`

This happens, because `<` is used in HTML sourcecode, for tags.

**EDIT**

If you want to replace them between .jsp pages, follow this [tutorial](http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/10/how-to-escape-html-special-characters-JSP-Java-Example.html).

Comment: I know, but how can i do that? Someone who doesn't know won't be able to use &lt; instead..

Comment: You mean that it does not reach your backend? Or something from backend is not displayed here?

Comment: No, i meant that this form will be used by people who don't know about this problem and maybe they will use that character there.

Comment: I have two jsp pages. In the first one i have a list of messages, in the second one i can edit those messages. So when i use a character like < in the edit page, it is displayed correctly, but i cannot see it in the message list page. I don't know if i explained right.

Comment: It seems, that you need to replace them then. Here you have a tutorial on how to do it on your message list page: http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/10/how-to-escape-html-special-characters-JSP-Java-Example.html

Comment: @Raz N Could you please upvote the answer as well? :)

Comment: Sure, i tried but i can't because i have under 15 reputation, i just created my account yesterday. I'll do that after i raise the rep i promise